# Obtaining Outlook build numbers which map to the introduction of a particular Mailbox API requirement set

Tags: ms-office, outlook-addin

I am trying to identify the build number (version) at which point a particular Mailbox API was introduced. As an example, the Mailbox API v1.2 was introduced in build 15.0.4719.1001 for Outlook 2013 for windows. The only source of information that I have been able to find was by going through the technet wiki found here [1].  Are there any other sources of information that I can consult to get these build numbers?

I still need to find details for the following mappings:

- Outlook 2013 for Windows -> v1.1
- Outlook 2016 for Mac  -> v1.1
- Outlook 2016 for Mac  -> v1.1

I have been so far been able to map the build numbers to the following versions:

Outlook 2013  for Windows:

- v1.2 -> Build 15.0.4719.1001
- v1.3 -> Build 15.0.4719.1001

Outlook 2016  for Windows

- v1.3  -> Build 16.0.4366.1000

**References**

[1] https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31133.outlook-and-outlook-for-mac-update-file-versions.aspx